# getting download file instead of index.html

Tags: apache, mamp

When I attempt to access localhost instead of index.html displaying, i get a download file.

this was working fine earlier, with no changes to server settings. The only thing I did was update some files via FTP.

this is the error displayed via the chrome console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php: "http://localhost:8888/index.html".
```

I have looked at the other answers and putting this inside the httpd.conf file did not help me

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .phtml
```

Comment: Have you tried changing permissions of the index.html file?

Comment: Add the permission are 644, i even tried to give them all 777 but to no effect

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution?